# Dimensions dont match between objects

Tags: transforms, units, dimensions

I have 3 models in my scene. 
One of them has the dimensions like I want it to have:
The Z dimension is 1m.

[image: what I want]

However, the other two models have a messed up dimension. They look right, but the panel says they are over a meter high, even though they are not:

[image: Too high!]

In relation to each other, everything seems fine though:

[image: seems fine]

However in edit mode, the two objects seem to have the correct length:
[image: length seems right]

I could **NOT** fix this by applying the scale.

How do I fix this? If I set the dimension of the two objects to what I want them to be, they are really small compared to the barrel.
It seems like there is somehow a global scale/dimension mismatch between these objects.

Thanks!

Comment: That can be an isolated vertex somewhere

Comment: or because your origin isn't right. Could you upload a blend file

Comment: @lemon you were right, what an obvious error I missed! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: RunOrVeith, this is a little error that can happen to everyone, but I think the comment is clear enough (and an answer won't provide more information). Thanks